# Modify column values based on a condition

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
Pollster    Banned   Grade
0   Monmouth University     no  A+
1   Selzer & Co.    no  A+
2   ABC News/The Washington Post    no  A+
3   Siena College/The New York Times Upshot     no  A+
4   Field Research Corp. (Field Poll)   no  A/B
```

I would like to change the values of the column Grade so that

- A+ --> A
- A- --> A
- A/B --> B

I have managed to change the A/B to B with the following command

```
pollster_ratings['Grade_1'] = pollster_ratings['538 Grade'].str.split("/",1).str[1]
pollster_ratings.head()

Pollster    Banned   Grade  Grade_1
0   Monmouth University     no  A+  NaN
1   Selzer & Co.    no  A+  NaN
2   ABC News/The Washington Post    no  A+  NaN
3   Siena College/The New York Times Upshot     no  A+  NaN
4   Field Research Corp. (Field Poll)   no  A/B     B
```

But I don't know how to modify the other values one command only.

Can anyone help me with that (: ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression:

```
pollster_ratings['Grade_1'] = pollster_ratings['Grade'].str.replace('[+\-]$|^A/', '', regex=True)
```

Alternatively, you can also pass a dictionary with replacement values to `replace`.